# Convert awesomium webview to String

Tags: awesomium

I am new to awesomium and I only want to load a page using webview and get the current document to sting

`webView.Source = New Uri("http://www.google.com")`

Answer (score 1):

```cs
// somewhere in your code that initializes your webView...
webView.LoadingFrameComplete += new FrameEventHandler(WebView_LoadFramingComplete);


private void WebView_LoadFramingComplete(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsMainFrame)
    {
        JSValue html = view.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
     }
}
```